# Do Moore's tables really exist?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I recently have a lesson about quantum chemistry, and in one lesson we spoke about hyperfine stucture of elements.

The teacher give us something which looks to be an extract of Moore's tables here for the carbon. He said there are thousands of this tables which give the energy levels of many atoms.

But I search on the net and I only found things about electronic such as transistors et caetera... can you tell me the real name of this tables or how can I find them ?

Thank you in advance [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Yes, [Charlotte Emma Moore](http://www.phys-astro.sonoma.edu/brucemedalists//Sitterly/index.html) and her tables really exist(ed).

See [Atomic Energy Levels, 2nd edition](http://www.nist.gov/data/nsrds/nsrdsnbs3-1.pdf).

Comment: Moore's law probably does interfere drastically with such a search...